# Sorting dictionaries by largest values: class method

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to sort a specific dictionary and return a list of the top_n number of occurences. The dictionary is a collection of words from a txt document, with the 'key' being  a single word from the txt file and the 'value' being its  number of occurrences in the document.

I have the **init** method as follows:

```
def __init__(self:'Collection_of_words', file_name: str) -> None:
    '''  this initializer will read in the words from the file,
    and store them in self.counts'''
    l_words = open(file_name).read().split()
    s_words = set(l_words)
    self.counts = dict([ [word, l_words.count(word)] 
                        for word 
                        in s_words])
```

Now, one of my instance methods will return a list of strings of the 'top n' number of occurrences givin some int argument. I gave it a shot:

```
def top_n_words(self, i):
    '''takes one additional parameter, an int,
    <i> which is the top number of occurences. Returns a list of the top <i> words.'''


    return [ pair[0] 
             for pair 
             in sorted(associations, key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)[:5]]
```

However, whenever i run this code i get errors and cannot figure out why. I'm not sure how to sort dictionary objects(eg. self.counts)

Comment: Do you just need this to work, or are you trying to figure out the way to do this as a learning exercise? There's a built in class that will do this for you in a more efficient manner, `collections.Counter`.

Comment: No i'm trying to figure this out as a learning exercise with out the help of collections.Counter.

Answer (score 3):

```
sorted(self.counts, key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)
```

Iterating over `self.counts` gives the keys, not key-value pairs. That means `pair[1]` won't work. You want `key=self.counts.get`.

If your list needs to include counts as well as keys, you'll need to instead sort the key-value pairs by values:

```
sorted(self.counts.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Also, note that [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) already does what you need, and with a counting algorithm in linear time instead of quadratic.

Comment: You could also use `sorted(self.counts.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)`. Normally I'd favor that, but since you're only looking for the keys (`pair[0]` in your original call) using `get` might be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating variable 'associations' containing dict_items. e.x.:

```
associations = self.counts.items()

>>> associations
>>>dict_items([('would,', 1), ('Even', 1), ('Cries', 1), ('Sings', 5)])
```

I then used this variable in a list comprehension. I sorted associations in descending order(largest to smallest) by creating a lambda function and indexing the second element in the pair. The word with the largest number of occurrences will be at index [0] in the list.

```
def top_n_words(self, i):

    associations = self.counts.items()

        return [ pair[0] 
             for pair 
             in sorted(associations, key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)[:i]]
```