# How does collections.Counter achieve fast sort time?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, collections, counter

Lately I've been playing around with Python's [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) data structure.  The canonic use of this object is to count the number of occurrences of words in a text file:

```
from collections import Counter

with open(r'filename') as f:
    #create a list of all words in the file using a list comprehension
    words = [word for line in f for word in line.split()]

c = Counter(words)
```

The cool part is how you can use this structure to figure out which words are the most common:

```
for word, count in c.most_common():
    print word, count
```

The part I don't understand is that `most_common()` [runs in O(n) time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21653556/3124423) [Edit: this is incorrect.  Based on Martijn's answer, it actually runs in O(n log k)].  Obviously that means it can't be doing a comparison sort with a dict behind the scenes, because the fastest comparison sort is O(nlogn).

**So how does collections.Counter achieve fast sorting time?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does **not** run in O(n) time. When you ask for *all* values in the dictionary a regular sort is used, a O(NlogN) algorithm.

When asking for a top K results, a `heapq.nlargest()` call is used, a more efficient approach in O(NlogK) time:

```
def most_common(self, n=None):
    '''List the n most common elements and their counts from the most
    common to the least.  If n is None, then list all element counts.

    >>> Counter('abcdeabcdabcaba').most_common(3)
    [('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('c', 3)]

    '''
    # Emulate Bag.sortedByCount from Smalltalk
    if n is None:
        return sorted(self.iteritems(), key=_itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return _heapq.nlargest(n, self.iteritems(), key=_itemgetter(1))
```

The answer talks about the *counting* being done in linear time; constructing the `Counter` instance, basically a loop over the input iterable:

```
for elem in iterable:
    self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + 1
```

Comment: "when asking for a top N results" - replace N with K for consistency with O(NlogK).

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks!  Just to make sure, here's how I understand the call to `most_common(k)`, based on you answer: 
1) A heap of size K is created. 
2) The algorithm steps through all N items in the dict and checks to see if the item is greater than the minimum item in the heap. 
3) If the new item is greater, it is added to the heap and the smallest item is deleted.  
Since step three can happen at worst N times, and costs at worst log(k), that gives us the total NlogK.  Does that sound right?

Comment: FWIW, the ``O(n log k)`` time for heapq.nlargest() is the worst case when the input data is reversed sorted.  For average cases (or random inputs), the number of is comparisons is roughly ``n + k * (log(k, 2) * log(n/k) + log(k, 2) + log(n/k))``.  That means that for a large *n* and small *k*, the *nlargest()* call is nearly linear and uses only a few more comparisons than *min()*.  See more detail in the notes at https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5262dd507ee5/Lib/heapq.py

Answer (score 1):

The sort isn't the part that runs in linear time. That takes O(nlog(k)), where n is the number of items in the counter and k is the number of items you requested from `most_common`. The *counting* takes linear time. It basically does this:

```
for item in iterable:
    self[item] = self.get(item, 0) + 1
```